# What does "ls -t . | while read line" mean?

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, ls

Here is the code:

```
if test $# -eq 1
then
  if test $1 = "--exec"
  then
    ls -t . | while read line
    do
      if test -f $line -a -x $line
      then
        echo $line
      fi
    done
  fi
fi
```

I don't understand the utility of  **`.`**  here in    `ls -t . | while read line`; can you explain?

Comment: `ls -t .` lists all non-hidden items in the current dir (`.`) , sorted by last-modified date in descending order (`-t`) - http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls+-t+.

Comment: All the output of ls -t . is redirect to the input of the read line.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs after you know what the code is about, you should be aware that you should never parse file names using `ls`

Comment: so .  is associated with ls ?

Comment: HuStmpHrrr  isn't my code , i think the best to use is dir

Comment: If none of your file names contain newlines, you can (and should) use double quotes around each instance of `$line` (e.g. `echo "$line"`) to prevent problems and misinterpretations.  If any of your file names contains a newline, your code will misinterpret that file name as two names — which will generally lead to unhappiness.  The `.` after `ls` is optional in this context; `ls` will print the files in the current directory anyway if you don't specify a file or directory to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line lists all the files in the present directory in ascending order of their modification time. The pipe operator sends the result of the directory listing to the while loop, which reads in each line from the ls command into the variable "line".  When I do this kind of thing, I usually use a foreach loop, but either way works.

Comment: i understand what the line does , but my real  question is ,  why  the   .   appear  her ls -t  .        because we can only do this ls [options] name ,    so    -t  and . are 2 options ?

Comment: @Alba: At the risk of repeating myself: `.` in POSIX-like shells represents the _current directory_. Here it serves as the _operand_ (non-option argument) to the ls command; i.e., what directory `ls` will operate on; `-t` is an _option_ (one that does _not_ take an _option-argument_) that outputs the names of (non-hidden) file/subdirectories in reverse chronological order (most recently modified one first).

Comment: My god ... I complicated this ...  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

your code simply prints out all executables in current folder, order by modification time.

generally shell scripting is very risky, since you can code very error prone or bad style code without actually realizing it. or even if you do, you may not have a correct understanding to the problems.

to achieve the same goal, I would write the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zk 1nr | sed -z 's/^[^ ]* //'
```

it's much concise and has no room for errors.

Comment: A clever solution; it's worth mentioning that you're relying on _GNU_-specific features (Linux), and that the `sed` command's _output_ will also be `NUL`-terminated, and that the filenames will be `./`-prefixed (use `%f` instead of `%p` to get the filenames only).